# How to display image in a HTML page the Django Framework?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a webpage which will show the logo of an music album. For that I've added a database field named album_ logo and add the path name of the images folder "C:\Python Projects\Test_App\website\music\static\music\Image" in database. But in the HTML page album_logo is not rendering.

```
Here is the attached code snippet.

<body>
{% load static %}
<img src = "{{album.album_logo}}">

<h1>{{album.album_title}}</h1>
<h3>{{album.artist}} - {{album.genre}}</h3>
</body>
```

## Create your models here.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + '-' + self.artist
```

Example: For the first album I've added the image path in database as - "C:\Python Projects\Test_App\website\music\static\music\Image\The_Division_Bell.jpg"

Comment: please post your models.py too :)

Comment: does the image have successfully uploaded into your database

Comment: @SubhajitPodder you need to add that model into your question not in the comment.Please edit your question with your model

Comment: `album_logo` should be image field not a charfield since it is a image

Comment: @user11418935 But I've added the path of the image inside double quotation not directly adding the image in DB.

Answer (score 2):

`album_logo` should be ImageField since it is a image.
Also you need to do `pip install pillow` to upload the images.

In your models

```
.......................
album_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='alubm_logo')
```

and in your project's urls.py you need to provide the static url like this
(Note:this is only for development)

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[.......
 ................
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Thanks for assistance. I've a few more things to ask, I've music app inside the website. Where shall I add the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT? What will be the values of these? I.e [MEDIA_URL = static\music\Image\]

Comment: in your settings.py  it should be by default.If not you can add it.see my answer.